# HDD Painfully Slow, Attempting To Do a Data Recovery

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, data-recovery, hard-drive-failure

I had a WD Blue 1TB drive in my laptop until 3 weeks ago where it violently froze on me. I have been trying to recover a document full of wedding photos for a family member. Though I am having no luck. I have gone from one technique to the other (USB to SATA, plugged it into my PC via SATA, wrote a File Filter in Java) but no matter what the I cannot get into the hard drive due to how slow it is.

Every I try to read from the HDD, it's speed goes up to 4.1 kb/s, active time 100% and the response time varying from 100ms to 10,000ms+. It also seems to only read the hard drive every 30 seconds as well.

Can I do anything else or is the data on that hard drive completely unrecoverable?

Thanks,
Duke

Comment: A hdd recovery service might have more luck.  Depending on the reason the HDD is behaving the way it is.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. You are talking about getting "into the drive" but some parts are damaged. So you should not "get into it", but you should make a proper bitstream copy first. You might want to check this: [Raw copy from failed hard disk](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/31377/19806)

Comment: protip. Always have a backup *before* you need one. If it matters you should have two of it, in different places

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to hear about your issues with the WD Blue! :( However, I'd definitely agree with the suggestion that a professional data recovery company is your best bet on getting any of those files back. Doing these attempts at your own risk and without actually [determining the health and SMART status of the WD Blue](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=OVnj8a) is pretty dangerous for the content.

You have done a great job with the troubleshooting so far, though. However, I'm afraid that the hard drive has failed. I'd suggest you check our [Data Recovery Partners](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=Sl8UDT) and ask them for assistance.

It might also be a good idea to check [the warranty status on the WD Blue](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=ah2sCU). If it's still covered, you should be able to RMA the product after the data recovery and get a replacement from us. For more details, make sure you contact our [Customer Support](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=fMoaWi).

Hope this was helpful. Good luck!